# Automatic split a mosaic of satellite images into pieces

Tags: arcgis-desktop, splitting, mosaic, satellite, image-segmentation

I have a mosaic of satellite images, but for the analysis, I need to define the boundaries of each part. Does anyone know how to do it in an automatic way?
I need to get the red boundaries like on the second image but in an automatic way(please do not offer a manual digitization option). 
[image]

[image]

I'm looking for some tool or algorithm that can help to make those boundaries automatically (there's a lot of similar). Maybe some raster processing techniques or should I dig in machine learning?

Comment: No, I mean each different element in each of that three rasters

Comment: Do you need a boundary for a whole raster, including "No Data" area, or just footpronts for imaged area?

Comment: I've clarified my question. Please check it again.

Comment: I don't think it is possible if your msaic is already merged composite.

Comment: can you clarify if your mosaic is a single file (e.g. GeoTiff) or Virtual Raster? Also, are the red boundaries in the second image of your question, individual polygons in a vector (shapefile) file?

Comment: Yes, my mosaic is a single file. And I need to get boundaries of each image in the mosaic (like those, I digitized in red lines).  And yes red polygons are a vector file.

Comment: I'm looking for some tool or algorithm that can help to make those boundaries automatically (there's a lot of similar). maybe some raster processing techniques or maybe should I dig in machine learning?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to split the image divided by those lines, so using spatial information. You can try segmentation of satellite imagery in ArcGIS pro (keeping all its properties an bands information), there you can also define spatial and spectral parameters as per your need.

I tried doing so using your imagery as an image just to try, using different parameters.

[image]

[image]

I guess you can also control these parameters more accurately by performing segmentation using python.

Answer (score 0):

You may try some edge detection filters like [this](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/i.zc.html) one to automatically highlight the 'edges' caused by sharp tonal variations which are quite apparent in your mosaic.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend the [Image Footprint plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/imagefootprint_plugin/) for QGIS. You can point it at a directory of images and it yields a shapefile with polygon boundaries of either valid pixels or bounding boxes of each image in the directory. The plugin also creates useful metadata within the polygon attributes.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score -2):

I see you are using ArcMap so:

1- Put all you images in one directory

2- Open ArcCatalog and create a temporary geodatabase

3- Rightclick inside Geodatabase and create a new "Mosaic Dataset" (name it whatever and chose the coordinate same as your images)

4- Than right click in Mosaic created and choose "Add Rasters..."

5- In new dialog table, choose as source the folder which are stored your images. (make sure "Update Boundary" is checked, by default it should be checked) click OK

6- open a blanck arcmap and load this Mosaic Dataset, you will have a layer footprint which contains what you are requesting (also attributes with images name).

Comment: The problem is that I haven't that rasters separately. I only have this mosaic and want to get all the pieces which are parts of it. So it is like an inverse problem.

Comment: Take a look here, they say it can be done also with .sid files
https://community.esri.com/thread/92029

Comment: Thank you, but it seems that they solve another task in that discussion (tiling, not defining the boundaries)

Comment: Ok sorry, i thought that the boundaries that you are requesting are different tiles